# Confusion about using external libraries in c++

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

In c/c++ we use -I for specifying header files location and -L path for specifying library path. I have an eigen and boost libraries, so what I did is that I copied these libraries to /usr/include directory in linux and in source file of my program I just used the header file of these libraries. My question is how does the source file of these libraries get linked with my program source file in which I am only using header files of these libraries?

Comment: Depends on what you use... If you only use templates from those libraries, for instance, header files contains usually everything, so there might be no need to link.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the libraries you are using. Eigen3 is header-only: no need to link against it. With Boost, it depends. Most parts are header-only but some libraries might need to be linked.

On the copying to `/usr/include`. This sounds horribly wrong. Use the package manager of your distribution to get a package of the libraries you require. You should almost never put files yourself into `/usr/{include|lib...}` directly but prefer `/usr/local/{include|lib...}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are also a little confused about source code and object code.  Generally, a library will contain compiled, object, code, but C++ template expansion requires some kind of source code or source-like code in order to perform template instantiation.

However, the bottom line is that the syntax to include a library depends on the compiler/linker combination you are using.  You need to state that before someone can answer the question fully.

The directory "/usr/include" is considered special, part of the operating system or platform you are using, so you should not copy files into it.

Note that the construction "c/c++" is not very meaningful - the two languages C and C++ have different syntax and different linkage models.  Best to say which one you meant.